# How to list great-grandchildren PIDs of target PID from a Bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, pid

I need to write script which displays the PID's of all the great-grandchildren of the processes whose PID's are given as argument.

The following script displays grandchildren of the processes whose PID's are given as argument but I need great-grandchildren.

```
#!/bin/env bash

display_cpid() {
    local depth=$1 pid=$2 child_pid
    (( ++depth ))
    while IFS= read -r child_pid; do
        if (( depth < 2 )); then
            display_cpid "$depth" "$child_pid"
        else
            echo "$child_pid"
        fi
    done < <(pgrep -P "$pid" | xargs)
}

display_cpid 0 "$1"
```

I expected script displays great-grandchildren but it displays grandchildren.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to make this script to display great-grandchildren.

Answer (score 0):

The condition 'depth < 2' control the "depth" of the process IDs that are printed. Consider changing '2' to '3' to print the great-grandchildren of the selected process.

Side note: The script fail to execute under Mint-19, consider a modified version:

```
#!/bin/bash
display_cpid() {
    local depth=$1 pid=$2 child_pid
    (( ++depth ))
    pgrep -P "$pid" | while read -r child_pid; do
        if (( depth < 3 )); then
            display_cpid "$depth" "$child_pid"
        else
            echo "$child_pid"
        fi
    done 
}

display_cpid 0 "$1"
```